# Connecting PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, wamp

I've been trying to add some php code to make my html document send an email based on the form the user puts in but I can't get the connection between php and html to work. Using WAMP and I have a .htaccess file that looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
AddType application/httpd-php .htm .html
```

When I go to my webpage and enter my name, email and a message I get this on my browser instead of "You've gotten mail" or something.:

[image]

Comment: You can't run PHP in a .html file, you'd need to change the extension to .php

Comment: How do you acce to your php page? something like _localhost/your-project/page.php_?

Comment: @MarkOverton, this is not exactly true as you can configure the webserver to process any extension via PHP interpreter, including `.html` or even `.overton` :)

Comment: @mitkosoft interesting

Comment: @MarkOverton, more here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/php-custom-file-extension/

Comment: Please do not post code as an _image of_ code. Show it in text form & properly formatted.

Comment: `AddType application/httpd-php .htm .html` <- the OP is already attempting to force Apache to interpret *.html* files as PHP (which means it should crank up the PHP interpreter).

Comment: I posted img to show how my browser reacts. So if I change file to index.php and $_post to $_POST it should work? I tried it now and that didn't do it.                   <?php include("php/send_form_email.php");?> is my include right above my form btw

Comment: Don't upload images of text. That is very difficult to read, and for the visually impaired it can be impossible to read. It also can't be indexed or searched. Please copy-paste the text directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and change `$_post` into `$_POST`. Variables are case sensitive in PHP. So, with `$_post` you are referring to something different from `$_POST` - the super global.
Also, I'm not quite sure about `header("Location: index.php?mailsend")`. Usually you would want to provide a value for URL parameters, like `index.php?mailsend=true`.

EDIT: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) question discussion as well. They discuss a similar problem to what you have: page shows PHP code instead of executing it. The answer in there details multiple potential fixes for an issue like this. There is likely an issue with your server configuration. Plus, there are more sources that you can find, similar to that, like [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/php-code-showing-instead-of-running-2694209) article.

Comment: Changed it but it doesn't seem to work, still opens the php file code in my browser.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page